# ARC retain cycle with completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

How to fix ARC retain cycle in following code ?

```
-(void) processRequest:delegate:(id<Delegate>)delegate {

__block  Request * request;
request = [[Request alloc] completionHandler:^(Response * response){

    [delegate removeCachedRequest:request];

    if (completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(response);
    }

}];
```

}

Comment: Why `__block Request *request`?

Comment: Need to access "request" variable inside a block. So __block varible is used.

Comment: No, you only need `__block` if you are going to *overwrite* the variable within the block.  You don't do that.

Comment: @Droppy: No, that is not true. You also need `__block` to be able to see changes to the variable outside the block after the block was created from inside the block. This is what is happening here. The `__block` IS needed.

Comment: @newacct But `request` is created outside the block and not written to within the block.

Comment: @Droppy: It doesn't matter. `__block` is not only useful for being written to inside the block. It's also useful for being written to outside the block and being able to see it inside the block. `request` is assigned to after the block is created. That assigned value would not be visible inside the block if it were not `__block`.

Comment: Where is `request` assigned after the block is created?

Comment: @Droppy: The assignment statement, `request = ...`. The right hand side of an assignment is evaluated before the assignment, and the right hand side is a method call, where the arguments are evaluated before the call. So 1) the block is created, then 2) the init (or `completionHandler:`) call is made, passing the block, and then 3) the return result is assigned to `request`.

Comment: Hmm that's fairly subtle, especially given the variable going out of scope when the outer method returns.